SonarQube Showing all project Issues instead from files related in PR
We have Dot Net project and we are using SonarQube to check for Code quality.   Recently we did modification in azure-pipelines.yml did version update . While raising PR now SonarQube is showing Issues from overall main branch instead of showing issues in PR related files from new branch which was created from main branch.
azure-pipelines.yml :
# ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting the full .NET Framework.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core.

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - develop
    - main
  paths:
    exclude: # cannot use variables here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#branches
    - src/api/Project1.Worker

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  name: Default

variables:
  - name: SolutionPattern
    value: '**/*.sln'
  - name: BuildConfiguration
    value: 'Release'
  - name: DotNetVersion
    value: '8.x'
  - name: NodeVersion
    value: '20.x'
  - name: WebAppDir
    value: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/api/Project1.Web'
  - name: ClientAppDir
    value: '$(WebAppDir)/app'


steps:

- checkout: self
  displayName: 'checkout'
  fetchFilter: tree:0

- task: SonarQubePrepare@7
  inputs:
    SonarQube: 'SonarQube'
    scannerMode: 'dotnet'
    projectKey: 'Project1_AYztzHohk_6xxaGPJ34n'



# *** start: frontend
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '$(NodeVersion)'
  displayName: 'ui: use node $(NodeVersion)'
  
# see: https://pnpm.io/continuous-integration#azure-pipelines
- script: |
    corepack enable
    corepack prepare pnpm@latest-9 --activate
    pnpm config set store-dir $(pnpm_config_cache)
  displayName: "ui: setup pnpm"
  
- script: pnpm install
  displayName: "ui: pnpm install"
  workingDirectory: $(ClientAppDir)

- script: npx kendo-ui-license activate
  displayName: "ui: setup kendo-license"
  workingDirectory: $(ClientAppDir)

- script: pnpm build
  displayName: "ui: pnpm build"
  workingDirectory: $(ClientAppDir)
# *** end: frontend



# *** start: backend
- task: UseDotNet@2
  name: 'InstallSDK'
  displayName: 'backend: use dotnet $(DotNetVersion)'
  inputs:
    version: '$(DotNetVersion)'
    performMultiLevelLookup: true
    
- task: NuGetAuthenticate@1
  displayName: 'backend: nuget authenticate'
  inputs:
    nuGetServiceConnections: 'TelerikNuget'

# WARNING: don't use DotNetCoreCLI@2 to restore package:
#
# - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
#   condition: ne(variables.NUGET_PACKAGES_RESTORED, true)
#   displayName: 'backend: restore'
#   inputs:
#     command: 'restore'
#     feedsToUse: 'config'
#     nugetConfigPath: 'nuget.config'
#     externalFeedCredentials: 'TelerikNuget'
#
# It adds a "feed-tickr" and removes existing "tickr" feed mentioned in nuget.config
# Since the packageSourceMapping doesn't exist for such a feed, restore fails.
#
# see https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/11406 
# and https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/15542
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'backend: nuget restore'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
        dotnet restore --nologo --use-lock-file $(WebAppDir)
        dir "tests\*.csproj" -Recurse | %{dotnet restore --nologo --use-lock-file $PSItem.FullName}

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'backend: build'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      dotnet build --nologo --configuration $(BuildConfiguration) $(WebAppDir)
      dir "tests\*.csproj" -Recurse | %{dotnet build --nologo $PSItem.FullName}

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'backend: test'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      dir "tests\*.csproj" -Recurse | %{dotnet test --no-build $PSItem.FullName}

# using DotNetCoreCLI@2 instead of "dotnet publish" to get the zipAfterPublish feature
# but this triggers a build again. "nobuild" only works with "pack" not "publish" command.
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  name: 'publish'
  displayName: 'backend: publish artifacts'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/out'
    zipAfterPublish: True

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'backend: save artifacts'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/out' 
    publishLocation: 'Container'
# *** end: backend



- task: SonarQubeAnalyze@7

- task: SonarQubePublish@7



There is no PR trigger in the yaml, are you using branch policy? On the pipeline log, is the branch checked out correct? could be like branch@refs/pull/365/merge which is a dummy branch before merge complete.

May i know what update have you done on the yaml? If you use the original yaml content to run the pipeline, will it work fine?
